# table of opponents. Condition

Tags: php, mysql

```
 for ($i=1; $i < 10; $i++) { 
    $a = rand(1,6);
    $b = rand(1,6);
    if ($a != $b) {
        $mysqli->query("UPDATE `jpa` SET `war` = $b WHERE `id` = $a");
        $mysqli->query("UPDATE `jpa` SET `war` = $a WHERE `id` = $b");
    }
 }
```

It is necessary to compile a table of opponents. When executed, the same results are obtained, how can this be avoided?

Comment: **1 = 4**  
2 = 3  
**3 = 5  
4 = 1  
5 = 3**  
6 = 4

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to build 6 (3?) pairs of opponents, like teams of soccer. And the goal is to have each team only play once. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes that's right, @Jeff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with an array of ids.

```
$ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
```

shuffle them

```
shuffle($ids);
```

then split into chunks of 2 and iterate those, doing your updates.

```
foreach (array_chunk($ids, 2) as $opponents) {
    if (count($opponents) == 2) {  // check this in case you have odd numbers of ids
        list($a, $b) = $opponents;
        $mysqli->query("UPDATE `jpa` SET `war` = $b WHERE `id` = $a");
        $mysqli->query("UPDATE `jpa` SET `war` = $a WHERE `id` = $b");
    }
}
```

Comment: but how to do it randomly? So values go in a row 2,1,4,3,6,5

Comment: `shuffle($ids)` should take care of that, unless I've misunderstood you.

Comment: @Syscall true! I just used a static array for example, but I assume the array of ids will probably come from a db query at some point anyway and may not actually be a continuous set of numbers.

Answer (score 1):

here's another approach, that I'll post just because I tried it and it's working.      @DontPanic's approach is better, though.

```
<?php

$teams = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
$played=[];

while(count($teams)) {
    $a=$teams[0];    // take the first avaiable team
    array_splice($teams,0,1);    // remove it off the list
    $j = rand(0,count($teams)-1);  // randomly choose an opponent
    $b = $teams[$j];
    array_splice($teams,$j,1); // remove the opponent from the list

    $mysqli->query("UPDATE `jpa` SET `war` = $b WHERE `id` = $a");
    $mysqli->query("UPDATE `jpa` SET `war` = $a WHERE `id` = $b");

    // optional for later use
    $opponents = [$a,$b];
    array_push($played, $opponents);
}

print_r($played);
```